# Absolutely position element based on center

Tags: javascript, html, css

A convenient way to make an absolutely-positioned hovering element that lets height vary with content using Javascript is to specify the width, top and left as style fields.  For instance:

```
popup.style.width  = foo.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
popup.style.top    = document.getElementById(bar)
    .getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px'; // for IE7, can't use offsetTop
popup.style.left   = '15px';
```

How can I adapt this code to absolutely position the popup based on its center, rather than its top?  I'd like to do `popup.style.center` instead of `popup.style.top`, but that's not how CSS works.  A completely naive solution is to add it to the DOM, then measure its height, and subtract half the height from the top.

Alternatively, is there a completely different approach that would still allow setting an arbitrary position for each corner of the element?

I'm looking for a pure Javascript solution (e.g. no jquery).

*Important*: I'm not trying to center the popup inside another element.  Rather, I want the center point of the popup to be specified as a pixel offset from the top of the screen.  This pixel offset may be based on another element, or it may be a raw number.

Comment: Read [Absolute Centering](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt)

Comment: Can you calculate the height of the popup and use that to center it?

Comment: @ggundersen The height isn't known until it's added to the DOM.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your important note you are dealing with two different notions:

- The first one, offset from the top of the screen, can be achieved with `position:fixed`.
- The second one, offset based on another element, is where absolute positioning is useful, and will be relative to the first `position:relative` parent element.

As suggest [Table-Cell centering](http://s.codepen.io/shshaw/fullpage/gEiDt#Table-Cell) (thanks to Itay comment) it makes sense in your case to use table display because it's exactly its purpose: adapt the container to its content.

You need some extra html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="content">
      <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And apply this css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute; /* or fixed */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.popup {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks to the table-cell display you can use `vertical-align: middle`, no more need of javascript.

For horizontal centering you can still add a classic `width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;` on popup class.

Comment: Regardless of whether I use `position:fixed` or `position:relative` inside `position:absolute`, I still need to measure the height *after* adding the element to the DOM.  Also, `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` don't help here; I'm not sure what you're going for with those.

Comment: You are right, my first answer didn't address you problem. With this one you don't need javascript anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in jquery would be pretty simple

DEMO [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/GbDw9/2895/)

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
$("div.target").center(true);
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `outerHeight()` gives the height of my element without actually adding it to the DOM?  That's the piece I'm missing with my existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had been thinking about this for a while.  You can actually absolute position an element from the center of a container instead of the corners by adding a div inside the container.  This inner container, or reference container, is 50% height and 50% width of the parent container.  Then you can position relative to the bottom right corner.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="pointer pointer-1" data-name="pointer-1"></div>
    <div class="pointer pointer-2" data-name="pointer-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

This is the container we want to place pointers in

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

We use this container to get a center point that we can use as a reference.  We use the bottom right corner of this div as our reference point.

```
.container-inner {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Create a couple of targets 60px in diameter

```
.pointer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Center target one in the center of the container

```
.pointer-1 {
  bottom: calc(-0% - 30px);
  right: calc(-0% - 30px);
}
```

Position target 2 25% right and down from the container center.

```
.pointer-2 {
  bottom: calc(-50% - 30px);
  right: calc(-50% - 30px);
}
```

You can see a working demo of this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/puqis/25/).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
.popup {
  margin-top: -50%;
}
```

Comment: [This site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) says that margin percentages are relative to the *containing* element, not the element itself.  In my case, it ends up in completely the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to just add the element to the DOM, measure its height, and subtract half the height from the top.  I make the element invisible before adding it, and visible again after adjusting the height, to avoid flickering.